# ctags for Razor/cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vim, razor, ctags

I was wondering if anyone knows of or has written a ctags definition for razor/cshtml. I would like to enhance my tags support in vim for my ASP.NET MVC applications.

I am looking for something similar to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/199338) (which adds stronger support for tags in javascript files) that I can through in my .ctags configuration file.

Here is a sample of the razor/cshtml syntax:

```
<!-- Single statement blocks  -->
@{ var total = 7; }
@{ var myMessage = "Hello World"; }

<!-- Inline expressions -->
<p>The value of your account is: @total </p>
<p>The value of myMessage is: @myMessage</p>

<!-- Multi-statement block -->
@{
    var greeting = "Welcome to our site!";
    var weekDay = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
    var greetingMessage = greeting + " Today is: " + weekDay;
}
<p>The greeting is: @greetingMessage</p>
```

Comment: You should add a sample of razor/cshtml code so that someone could help you with that.

Comment: Essentially Razor/cshtml is a template language that allow one to intermingle c# and html. At the core lies the @ operator. When the parser comes across @ operator the syntax/language switches from html to c#. Here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/14cHW8k7) of the basic syntax. The pastebin snippet came from [this introduction](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax) to Razor.

Thanks for the question.